# AWS - Apache application behind app load server not using SSL certificate

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, elastic-load-balancer

I have placed my instances behind an ALB that has an ACM provided SSL certificate configured with it. However, when I browse to the web page (that I have configured via Route53's alias record to the App Load Balancer), it says that my connection is not secure. 
What am I doing wrong here? Do I need to configure Apache somehow?

Comment: Can you check the domain with certificate domain is the same including subdomain? Or do you see links appear in browser console highlighting an error saying mixed content? Normally you don't need to do a change in apache since SSL termination happens at ALB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got help from the following [site](https://www.davidmeents.com/blog/add-ssl-ec2-wordpress-instance-use-https/). Added the code below to an `.htaccess` file that I placed at the app root, i.e., `/var/www/html`.

Caveat: Be aware that even though my app was running behind a load balancer, `.htaccess` is disabled by default in EC2 as a security measure and therefore needs to be be enabled by editing `etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`, where you change `AllowOverRide = None` to `AllowOverRide = All`

**Code for `.htaccess`:**

```
# Begin force ssl
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://your-domain/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

Restart apache once you've got this in there. `sudo service httpd restart`.

If it still doesn't work, clear browser cache. If it doesn't work for `www.your-domain.com`, it is quite possible that you ordered the certificate for `your-domain.com` only. Make a new certificate (they are free), with both names added to it.